# Res' does not exist in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt

I am having the issue in Eclipse:

**Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.**

Output:

```
[2011-08-23 07:57:04 - Penncat AQI] ERROR: resource directory 'C:\Users\Allison\Desktop\penncat app?\penncat app 822\res' does not exist
```

The res folder is there though...any suggestions?

I cleaned it, closed the project, exit eclipse, reopened it and still same issue above exists.

Comment: Maybe the blank space in the path is causing that error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've ran into this when upgrading my environment:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16585871/606351

Answer (score 3):

Mybe you path have a issue  “C:\Users\Allison\Desktop\penncat app?\penncat app 822\res“；my problem is the path have chinese character.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same error when I accidentally deleted my res folder.  It seems that folders that are recognized by the ADT are used.  You can see that in the package explorer, folders recognized by the ADT have an icon with 'a', if not, moving away the previous res folder and 'create new folder' in the package explorer would make one.

I guess there should be a better way to mark an existing folder as 'android resource folder', but I didn't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to your hardisk's directory from Android. You can only make use of your sdcard or internal memeory.

Comment: The question referes to Eclipse not finding the directory, rather than not finding the dir by code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your direction name maybe it has a invalid character,delete "?" in directory and make clean and buid your project

Answer (score 0):

My path has the ampersand symbol (&), so I had to change the project location to another one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating an empty "res" folder in the project in question.

In my case the error was:

```
[2015-08-10 16:52:37 - picasso] ERROR: resource directory '/Users/me/MyProject/Dependencies/Lib/picasso/picasso/res' does not exist
```

There was no `res` folder there, but by making an empty one this error went away and my workspace built again.