# Resource directory is not available

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Eclipse shows in the Problems tab that the resource directory is not available despite the fact it is available in the project folders tree :

```
[2012-09-11 12:14:43 - QR01] ERROR: resource directory 'D:\workspaceQR\QR01\res' 
does not exist
```

I tried to fix this error by rebuilding the path and I couldn't manage to solve it and also it gives me red exclaimation mark beside the project name.
Any suggestion why Eclipse says that my resource directory is not available?

Comment: Possible that your res folder might contain some error..or have not loaded properly..If you are working on existing code then try to import it again.

Answer (score 5):

For future reference:
This error could manifest when upgrading to SDK Tools r22.
After updating, you need to reopen the SDK Manager. Here you would find a new package - Android SDK Build-tools.
Get this as well, and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Is it situated at the same level as src folder?
Or have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: yes at the same level of the src folder and i didi clean the project